# Covariance Matrix with all equal entries

Tags: normal-distribution, stochastic-processes, gaussian-process

by training a Gaussian Process Regression Model I'm finding the weird result
where the resulting covariance matrix has all the entries equal between each others. 
I'm using a Gaussian kernel with additive noise as covariance function.
The calculation are all correct according to my checking...so I was thinking that what I'm trying to fit is actually white noise...
Don't know...any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example?

Comment: If it were white noise, the covariance matrix would be diagonal: all non-diagonal elements would be zero! 
If by "all the entries equal between each others" you mean that the covariance matrix is symmetric: well, that is the case for every covariance matrix.

Comment: Also, a covariance matrix with all entries equal to each other is impossible. Such a matrix would not be positive definite, as is required for the covariance matrix of Gaussian processes.

Comment: @StijnDeVuys , your statement that "a covariance matrix with all entries equal to each other is impossible" is incorrect according to my view of the world.  A matrix with all entries equal to each other is a symmetric rank one matrix, which is positive semidefinite, and hence a covariance matrix, and in one dimension is positive definite unless the entry is 0. I am not aware of any convention which disallows the covariance matrix of a Gaussian Process from being singular, and in any event, it is not disallowed according to my definition.

Comment: I neglected to explicitly mention that these identical elements must be non-negative.

Comment: @Mark L. Stone: You are right, a covariance matrix is positive semidefinite, and not necessarily positive definite. But if that matrix is the result of training a Gaussian Process regression model from noisy data, is it possible that the result is a rank 1 covariance matrix? In my opinion, that is not so. In all texts on GP regression, I see the requirement that the kernel is positive definite.

Comment: Well, a singular, let alone, rank one matrix, may not be a great regression result, but in my book (not written yet, ha ha), it's valid.  How about in one dimension?  Let's say the variance = 0.  What's wrong with that?  BTW, I'm not trying to imply that the OP"s calculations aren't screwed up.

Comment: What is your $\sigma_{noise}$?

Comment: When you say all entries are the same, do you mean all the off-diagonal elements, or all elements including the diagonal?

Answer (score 5):

If all elements of the covariance matrix are identical, including the diagonal, then you basically have a degenerate process. Suppose, for definiteness, that the index space is [0,1]. Then each realization of the process will be a horizontal line. The $y$ intercept of the lines will be normally distributed with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$, where $\sigma^2$ is the common variance/covariance entry.

If you meant to say that the covariances are equal but the diagonal repeats a different value ... then this would be consistent with the classic repeated measures design. Each realization would be white noise with the mean of the white noise varying from realization to realization.